# How to remove characters from a str in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following str I want to delete characters.

For example:

from `str1 = "A.B.1912/2013(H-0)02322"`
to `1912/2013`

from `srt2 = "I.M.1591/2017(I-299)17529"`
to `1591/2017`

from `str3 = "I.M.C.15/2017(I-112)17529"`
to `15/2017`

I'm trying this way, but I need to remove the rest from `(` to the right

`newStr = str1.strip('A.B.')`

`'1912/2013(H-0)02322'`

For the moment I'm doing it with **slice notation**

`str1 = "A.B.1912/2013(H-0)02322"`

`str1 = str1[4:13]`

`'1912/2013'`

But not all have the same length.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: `str1.split('(')[0]` as a starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex instead:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'\d+/\d+')

print(regex.search(str1).group())
print(regex.search(str2).group())
print(regex.search(str3).group())
```

Output:

```
1912/2013
1591/2017
15/2017
```

Answer (score 2):

With some (modest) assumptions about the format of the strings, here's a solution without using regex:

First split the string on the `(` character, keeping the substring on the left:

```
left = str1.split( '(' )[0]   # "A.B.1912/2013"
```

Then, split the result on the last `.` (i.e. split from the right just once), keeping the second component:

```
cut = left.rsplit('.', 1)[1]  # "1912/2013"
```

or combining the two steps into a function:

```
def extract(s):
    return s.split('(')[0].rsplit('.', 1)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `re.sub` here with a capture group:

```
str1 = "A.B.1912/2013(H-0)02322"
output = re.sub(r'.*\b(\d+/\d+)\b.*', '\\1', str1)
print(output)

1912/2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [regular expression](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) to solve this problem.

```
import re

pattern = r'\d+/\d+'

str1 = "A.B.1912/2013(H-0)02322"
srt2 = "I.M.1591/2017(I-299)17529"
str3 = "I.M.C.15/2017(I-112)17529"

print(*re.findall(pattern, str1))
print(*re.findall(pattern, str2))
print(*re.findall(pattern, str3))
```

**Output:**

```
1912/2013
1591/2017
15/2017
```